# Synchronous MSXML2.XMLHTTP producing "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available."

Tags: http, vbscript, runtime-error

In a VBScript, having instantiated:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

I am doing a sequence of synchronous HTTP PUTs like this:

```vb
xmlhttp.open "PUT", TheURL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type","application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept","application/json"
xmlhttp.send TheXML
If xmlhttp.readyState <> 4 Then
    xmlhttp.waitForResponse 1
End If
If xmlhttp.status >= 300 Then
    WScript.Echo "Failure: " & TheURL & "<BR>" & TheXML
End If
```

After a few I check for an error and discover:

> -2147483638: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

Given that I have made these using *synchronous* calls, how is this possible?  How can I avoid this error?

Comment: While your *calls* are synchronous, the server-side operations triggered by these calls may not be.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Right, but doesn't the `xmlhttp.waitForResponse` guarantee I wait for them to complete?  And even if they had not returned, is the `xmlhttp` object not available for ongoing use as described without raising this error?

Comment: As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `waitForResponse` is for asynchronous `send()` operations. You're doing a synchronous `send()`, so `waitForResponse` doesn't do anything in your case. If the application on the server returns immediately and runs whatever it's supposed to do asynchronously in the background I don't think there's anything you can do on the client-side but try and wait.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I suppose I have no need to use the ServerXMLHTTP object.  Using the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object would avoid this?

Comment: There's no telling without knowing what the server-side is actually doing, but I'd doubt it. Currently your question boils down to: "I'm calling some functions (won't tell you what they're doing), and sometime later I get this error. What's wrong?"

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is right, we need more information to help. At the moment it's all just guess work *(educated guess work but guess work nonetheless)*. Without some indication of what the server-side is doing we can't help much further. Have you tried `xmlhttp.open "PUT", TheURL, True` so you are making a async request?

Comment: An example of a `async` callback here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6712069/692942

Comment: @Lankymart: Well I confirmed that the error can be produced using async calls.  But that's the only time I can imagine it making sense.  If the `xmlhttp` object says `readyState = 1`, then why can't I get its `status`?  I.e., how else would I determine that datum is not yet available?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

To

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

And add this:

```
xmlhttp.setTimeouts 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you added an explanation of why this is the solution.