# How to call an ASMX webservice asynchronously from classic ASP?

Tags: web-services, asp-classic, asmx

Is anyone aware of whether this is possible?

I want to call a webservice asynchronously (fire and forget) from classic ASP?

Comment: How do you plan to call the service at all? How would you call it synchronously?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510497/how-do-i-fire-an-asynchronous-call-in-asp-classic-and-ignore-the-response

Comment: Do you control over the site offering the ASMX service?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little different, but I recently had another system that had to call a process that was very lengthy, I didn't want the asp page to timeout or error during the process.

I'd developed the process as a vbs file for this reason, and originally had it running on a schedule. I created an asp page to fire it using the shell object in classic asp. I was therefore able to initiate the .vbs script, and carry on with the asp page, on the assumption that the vbs did its stuff. I could have (but didn't) got it to update a record in the db at the end so that asp would know it had completed. Perhaps a similar approach might enable you do to the same fire and forget?