# How can I http post data to any page in the web in Classic ASP?

Tags: http, asp-classic

How can I http post data to any page in the web in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest `ServerXMLHTTP` over `XmlHttp` for the reasons below:

> XMLHTTP is designed for client
>   applications and relies on URLMon,
>   which is built upon Microsoft Win32
>   Internet (WinInet). ServerXMLHTTP is
>   designed for server applications and
>   relies on a new HTTP client stack,
>   WinHTTP. ServerXMLHTTP offers
>   reliability and security and is
>   server-safe.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761

Example:

```
    DataToSend = "id=1"
    dim xmlhttp 
    set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST","http://localhost/Receiver.asp",false
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send DataToSend
    Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see:

[System.Net.HttpWebRequest in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933553/system-net-httpwebrequest-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://yoursite", false
xmlhttp.Send data

Response.Write xmlhttp.ResponseText
```

Comment: Don't use XMLHTTP in ASP, use ServerXMLHTTP as @Jakkwylde indicates.

Comment: without adding the content type most posts will not accept this as a valid request

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to redirect a POST request, you can use Server.Transfer