# How to http Request pass in ASP pages

Tags: asp-classic, httpwebrequest

I want to implement http Web request in asp page

So please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific... please tell us what are you doing/trying to do! what do you want to send, etc...

Comment: I'm holding off on the close vote because this question is pretty unclear, but it _sounds_ like you want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933553/system-net-httpwebrequest-in-classic-asp

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help you: [Passing Values into ASP Pages](http://www.kamath.com/columns/squareone/so003_aspvalues.asp)