# Check another website html code using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to look at a website. They have three images displaying depending on a certain status.

The other website uses an image tag 
`<img src="http://website/123.png" id="ImageToDisplay">`

There are two images and the image name changes for example: 111.png, 222.png.

So when they update there page to 222.png my website should pick it up and also show 222.png.

Using javascript I can imagine using `getElementById("ImageToDisplay")`, not sure how to pull  from another website

I will be running the JavaScript with Classic ASP

Comment: How are you running the JavaScript? Node.js? Classic ASP?

Comment: @Quentin Classic ASP

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933553/system-net-httpwebrequest-in-classic-asp

Comment: you need to parse data from other site? web site can close showing they  img in other site by change a few string in server config. you better google for html data parsers, and read more about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript's built-in functions:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

jQuery

```
$.get(
    "somepage.php",
    {paramOne : 1, paramX : 'abc'},
    function(data) {
       alert('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
```

If you are using asp.net you should take a look at the [WebRequest Class here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Have fun !

Answer (score -1):

If you have [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) enabled, you can use [AHAH](http://www.xfront.com/microformats/AHAH.html) to insert the code from that page into a `<div>` with style `display:none;`. You can then `getElementById()` and access its `src` property

AHAH example:

`ahah('page.html','DivID');`

Src Fetching Example

`document.getElementById("img").src;`